# How to calculate the marks above and below the average using Generic in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to solve this question :

> Create a function of type **Generic** so that it receives 5 marks, regardless of the type of these marks. Calculate the average, calculate the marks **above** and **below** the average, and ***print the result on the screen.***

but I did not know how! , I do this but I don't know how to **display the marks above and below the average.**

and I am not sure if I solve the question in the right way.

```
using System;

namespace oopGeneric
{
    class Calculator
    {
       public int high = 0, low = 0;
        public double Sum<A, B, C, D, E>(int n1, double n2, double n3, int n4, int n5)
        {
           

            double sum = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5;
            Console.WriteLine("The Summation {0} ", sum);
            double avg = sum / 5;
                return avg;
        }
        class Program


        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Calculator calc = new Calculator();

                double sum = calc.Sum<int, double, double, int, int>(5, 5.5, 15.0, 6, 8);

              //  Console.WriteLine("above" + high);
                Console.WriteLine(sum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you means out params, Have you tried using out params[] for example, of this way you can do something linke this var c = Result<int>(1,2,3,4,5,6...,7);

Comment: @Fabio Andrés 
I am trying to send 5 values with different data types using generic and it should display the average of these values and display the values above the average and the values below the average

Comment: After calculating the average, you can loop through the values and check if they are above the average.

Comment: Are you sure your method shouldn't look like this: `Sum<T>(T a, T b, T c, T d, T e)`?

Comment: public double Sum<A, B, C, D, E>(A n1, B n2, C n3, D n4, E n5)
        {
      double r = 0;
   if (A is Int32 int32_a) r+= int32_a
    else if (A is Double dbl_a) r+= dbl_a;
                 ...   

            double avg = r / 5;
                return avg;
        }

Comment: you have to implement the do patter foreah parameter

Comment: @JonathanWood yes 
Yes you are right, but when I changed it I got some errors, how can I type it in the right way?

Comment: I would say this task makes no sense at all unless there are limits here we're not privy to. "Any type"? **Any** type? So calculating the "average" of 5 string marks is part of the task? If you use enum types, what does average then mean? "the one in the middle"? There's no average value for enums because they can't be fractional. I would ask for clarification for this task.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You are right, my teacher gave me this task and I am obliged to solve it in this required way, but I do not know what is the correct way and I did not understand what the teacher wants

Comment: @JonathanWood I'm sorry if I bothered you, but can you help me solve it as you said?

Comment: @Aldeek: I though others answered your specific question. I was just commenting that I only thought you were expected to create one type argument. At least, that made the most sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the method Sum, you can insert the code

```
 double avg = sum / 5;
 var marks = new double[]{n1,n2,n3,n4,n5};
 foreach (double m in marks)
    if (m > avg) Console.WriteLine(m);
```

You will get the marks above the average.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution using matching pattern.

```
    public double Sum<A, B, C, D, E>(A n1, B n2, C n3, D n4, E n5)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        sum+= (n1 is Int32 n1_as_integer) ? n1_as_integer :
         (n1 is Double n1_as_double) ? n1_as_double : 0;
         
        sum+= (n2 is Int32 n2_as_integer) ? n2_as_integer :
         (n2 is Double n2_as_double) ? n2_as_double : 0;

        return sum / 5;
            
    }
```

This is the solution using params + matching pattern.

```
    public double Sum(params object[] N)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        foreach(var i in N)
        sum+= (i is Int32 i_as_integer) ? i_as_integer :
         (i is Double i_as_double) ? i_as_double : 0;
         
        return (N.Lenght>0) ? sum / N.Lenght : 0;
            
    }
```

Comment: That's a huge performance sink and nearly defeats the purpose of using generics.

Comment: Of course, this solution defaults the concept, it is only for Generic "Hello World" proposal. Cast, covariance and contravariance hit the performance, even in IL level interfaces hit the performance.

Comment: Sum is like a Foo

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider accepting any [`IConvertible` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=net-5.0) as a *generic constraint*.

### `IConvertible`

An object that implements IConvertible  is required to implement public methods that either convert to the designated primitive runtime type(such as `int`, `float`) or throw an `InvalidCastException`.

These types include

```
bool      sbyte    byte
u/short   u/int    u/long
double    float    decimal  Single
DateTime  char     string
```

We can use `IConvertible` as a *constraint* to allow only objects that can be converted to primitives.

For example we could convert any of the above types(except the ones that aren't numbers they will throw `InvalidCastException`) to a double with this method.

```cs
double Convert<T>(T Value) where T : IConvertible
{
    return Value.ToDouble(null);
}

// These all work
Convert(10m);       // (decimal)
Convert(10);        // (int)
Convert(10f);       // (float)
Convert((sbyte)10);
Convert((long)10);
```

Using this we can construct an average function that can accept an atrocity such as this:

```cs
Average<IConvertible>(10, 10m, (ushort)10, (byte)10, (sbyte)10, 10f, 10d, (long)10, (ulong)10, (uint)10);
```

Which if we did everything right should ideally output `10d`;

```cs
public double Average<T>(params T[] numbers) where T : IConvertible
{
    // create a place to put the sum, since we need it to calculate the average later
    double sum = default;

    // store the length of the array since we use it in multiple places
    int count = numbers.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        // convert value to double, all primitive IConvertible types are required to cast to double(generally)
        double value = numbers[i].ToDouble(null);

        // add value to the sum so we can calculate the average later
        sum += value;
    }

    // return the average score
    return sum / (double)count; // cast int to double to avoid unintentional integer math
}
```

*Editors Note*
The above example assumes the requirement to use Generics. You can simplify the un-intuitive call for `Average<IConvertible>` for mixed-types with a solution such as  `Average(params IConverible[] numbers)`, however that would not be using generics.